# What kind of literacy device is "“Amen” stuck in my throat."?

Tags: literary-techniques

So what kind of literacy device is "“Amen” stuck in my throat"? This quote is found in Shakespeare's Macbeth.

Macbeth says:

> But wherefore could not I pronounce “Amen”? I had most need of blessing, and “Amen” Stuck in my throat.

He is treating a word as an object and as if it stuck on this throat. What could this be?

Comment: It’s ***metaphorical***

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was satisfactory. If it was, please upvote and accept it (as you see appropriate).  Otherwise, I'd be happy to clarify anything for you if you need me to!

Comment: That answer would suffice. Thanks @JohnB.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: @GoNK You're tryna say *literary device* and **not** literacy device, correct ? https://www.google.com/search?q=literary+device

Comment: The expression: "words stuck in my throat" is as old as the hills in English, still used and quite common. "words can stick in one's throat" for any number of reasons: surprise, anger, etc. etc. Although the answers covers the issue, it doesn't say those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's understand what the first sentence means before we look at "stuck in my throat."

> But wherefore could not I pronounce “Amen”?

**This sentence means (in *modern* English):**

> Why couldn't I say "Amen?"

---

Now, let's look at the second sentence.

> I had most need of blessing, and “Amen” Stuck in my throat.

**The first part ("I had...blessing") of the second sentence means:**

> I need God to bless me...

Macbeth *needed* God to bless him, **but** "Amen" was "stuck in my [his] throat."  This means that "stuck in my throat" has to be the reason that Macbeth couldn't say "Amen."

---

Now, we need a little bit of *context* from Macbeth to figure out why "Amen" is "stuck in my [his] throat."

Macbeth had killed the king, Dunkin, and felt **guilty.**

**When I feel guilty, sometimes it *feels* as if my throat is closing.  Shakespeare is using this feeling figuratively to explain why Macbeth couldn't say "Amen."  Shakespeare's choice of "stuck in my throat" makes it sound as if Macbeth's throat was *actually* closing, so the word "Amen" was blocked from reaching Macbeth's mouth and couldn't be spoken.**

*This is an example of a **metaphor (thank you, Kate Bunting, for your assistance).***

---

*Note: "Stuck in my throat" could also represent the fact that murdering Duncan was sinful, so Macbeth is *separated* from God and cannot receive blessings from God.*

Comment: He had heard one of the servants say 'God bless us' as a simple evening prayer, and the other reply [Amen](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amen). He wanted to say 'Amen' too, but couldn't get the word out.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, (correct me if I'm wrong) but the only context that is really needed to understand this is that Macbeth murdered Duncan and felt guilty after.

Comment: I was composing my own answer when yours appeared, so I discarded my draft - but I thought it possible that the OP didn't know the meaning of _Amen_.

Comment: @KateBunting OK.  I am having a hard time figuring out if "stuck in my throat" is a metaphor or imagery (I think it is both but am not sure).  What do you think?

Comment: I'd say a metaphor.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks.  I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the speaker is saying that he wants to say the word, But, the word would not come out of his mouthful to some blockage. In this case, it was for a psychological reason or a reason of conscience. For example, “I tried to lie and say that I was having a good time. But the words stuck in my throat.” Or, the phrase could be written to mean that the words would not come out of the speakers mouth for emotional reasons. As in, “I tried to give my beloved father’s eulogy. But, the words stuck in my throat.”

It is similar to the phrase, “tip of my tongue”. As in, “I recognize that person. And, I know that I should recall their name. But, their name is barely on the tip of my tongue.“

In another context, the phrase could be written to mean that the word could not come out for a physiological reason or from lack of familiarity. Such as, “I can read this foreign language. But, when I try to speak it, the words get stuck in my throat.“

Comment: The “tip of the tongue” phenomenon, as you wrote, is about **recall.**  In Macbeth’s case, he cannot **say** (“pronounce”) “Amen,” so it is not related to the “tip of the tongue” phenomenon.